# Lucene how can i turn off "toLowerCase" in StandardAnalyzer?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to tokenaze my text, I use tokenStream from StandardAnalyzer, but it has by default "toLowerCase".

My code:

```
        ArrayList<String> toTextWord = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

        try (TokenStream stream = analyzer.tokenStream("tags", new StringReader(iterStr))) {

            stream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
            stream.reset();
            while (stream.incrementToken()) {
                CharTermAttribute token = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
                System.out.println(token.toString());
                toTextWord.add(token.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can i use StandardAnalyzer without "toLowerCase"? How can i turn off "toLowerCase" in this StandardAnalyzer?

Comment: You don’t want to match if the case is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn off `toLowerCase` directly in the `StandardAnalyzer`.

You can create a custom analyzer which behaves the same way as the `StandardAnalyzer`, and then customize it to meet your needs:

Example using [`org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/custom/CustomAnalyzer.html):

```java
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
        .withTokenizer("standard")
        .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
        .addTokenFilter("stop")
        .build();
```

Now you can comment out (or remove) the lowercase token filter:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
        .withTokenizer("standard")
        .addTokenFilter("stop")
        .build();
```

Note that if you want to exactly match the default Standard Analyzer, then you should also comment out or remove the stop-word filter, since by default stopwords are not removed from the Standard Analyzer unless you provide an explicit list.

That gives us this:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
        .withTokenizer("standard")
        .build();
```

If I use the following input with my custom analyzer:

```
String iterStr = "Eric the quick brown fox jumps over Freddy the lazy dog, LOL.";
```

then the output from your code is as follows:

```
Eric
the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
Freddy
the
lazy
dog
LOL
```

---

**Update**

When using the `CustomAnalyzer` you can use string values to identify the different tokenizer and filter objects - such as "standard" and "lowercase", as used in my examples above.

If you want to avoid using these identifiers, you can use the relevant factory object with the `NAME` field:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
        .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.NAME)
        .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.NAME)
        .addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.NAME)
        .build();
```